# Visual Studio 2013 error

Tags: module, f#, visual-studio-2013, z3, fsc

The top line of my code 'module Title' is giving me a dual warning "The search directory 'C:\z3-4.3.0-x64\bin\' could not be found". One for my .fs (f#) file and one for some FSC file. I believe FSC is or has something to do with the main project file.

Although I suppose I could try placing a z3 library folder in that specific location, I really don't want to. I have to localize this project for portability. I'm not sure if that file path string is hardcoded or if it was generated from asking my system where things like that are supposed to be installed.

When I search for things like "The search directory" + "could not be found" + visual + studio, I don't get any interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

This path is not hardcoded in Z3 or in F#. It's possible that someone added it to the system settings, e.g., the PATH variable, but that wouldn't produce this warning. By the folder name, I would conjecture that somebody downloaded the Z3 distribution (.zip) and unzipped it in C:.

It can really only be something that's left over from previous projects, e.g., either in the project settings or in the global Visual Studio settings. It seems F# is searching for a module and while doing that, it finds that the directory doesn't exist, which is only a warning because finally all modules can be found elsewhere anyways.

Regarding 'FSC', that's the name of the F# compiler, quite possible that this name pops up in some error messages etc.